# How to remove JPanel from other class

Tags: java, jpanel, actionlistener

I have a few classes with some panels, buttons and so on... I combined everything together, but I have one problem.

In main class, i have "main" JPanel - working panel, which contains other JPanels - menu with buttons, and the second panel with the content table.

All I want is to remove that content panel after I click the button in menu panel.

JFrame and work-panel is one class in .java,
menu-panel is second class in other .java,
content-panel is third class in other .java,
actionperformed is placed in other .java file.

Here you have my ActionListener code with some comment.

I know I can make it easier and faster but I want to learn how to solve this problem and take control of all the elements in other classes. Java is my hobby not work. I'm doing this for my own satisfaction.

You don't have to write a full script. Please tell me which command will help with that or let me know where to find the answer. I don't want to copy and past but learn.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class zdarzenia extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("add_new")) {
            System.out.println("Working");

            /* here i want to place code which will delete content panel 
             * from JPanel "roboczy" in glowna() and add new JPanels
             */


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: it's worth having a look at `CardLayout` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).  This enables you to have lots of panels and swap between which one gets shown.

Comment: That will be simpliest and i think fastest way. Do you know how to do this without Layout managers? Is there any other way? That is theoretical question.